# AngularJS angular.equals working differently on ng-show

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, object-comparison

I have these lines in my controller

```
$scope.VLANEnabledServers = {};
$scope.myEmpty = {};
console.log(angular.equals($scope.myEmpty, $scope.VLANEnabledServers));
```

and this `ng-show` in the template

```
<table ng-show="!angular.equals(myEmpty, VLANEnabledServers)" ng-cloak class="table table-striped table-bordered ng-hide">
```

The `angular.equals` function in the controller prints `TRUE` which is correct. But in the view , where the condition in `ng-show` should be `!TRUE` the `table` is displayed anyways

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ngShow` directive takes an **[angular expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)** as an attribute.

An angular expression is limited in what it can contain, and, whilst it looks like javascript sometimes, actually isn't. See the linked page for more details of what is and isn't a valid angular expression.

What you'll most likely want to do is create a function on the scope to do the comparison for you, and then call that function from your expression:

```
$scope.isEmptyObject = function (item){
  return angular.equals( {} , item );
}
```

With:

```
<table ng-show="!isEmptyObject(VLANEnabledServers)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep this logic in the controller and it works (your dom can't eval the objects you send to the equals function your way)

```
$scope.VLANEnabledServers = {};
$scope.myEmpty = {};
$scope.showme = function() {
    return angular.equals($scope.VLANEnabledServers , $scope.myEmpty);
}

<table ng-show="!showme()" ng-cloak class="table table-striped table-bordered ng-hide">
```